# How does PolarPlot render a nested list of functions?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I am getting unexpected plots from `PolarPlot` when I provide a list of functions that I generate using `Table`.  I suspect the issue is related to the presence of nested lists, but I want to understand how `PolarPlot` is rendering the nested list of functions.

I expect the output to be a plot showing the curve of each function in my list.  I do not know what functional form would generate the plot that I do observe.

For example:

```
f[a_, b_, c_, t_] := 1 + (1/a)Sin[b + c*t]
t1 = Table[f[a, b, c, t], {a, 3}, {b, 0, Pi/2, Pi/2}, {c, 1}]
PolarPlot[t1, {t, 0, Pi}] (* Not expected result *)
PolarPlot[t1[[1, {1, 2}, {1}]], {t, 0, Pi}] (* Not expected result *)
PolarPlot[Flatten[t1], {t, 0, Pi}] (* Expected result *)
PolarPlot[t1[[1, {1, 2} ,1]],{t, 0, Pi}] (* Expected result *)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have already found the solution: to use `Flatten`. What happens here is that the `Table` command with several iteration arguments) creates a set of functions nested like this:

```
{{ {f1[t]}, {f2[t]} },{ {f3[t]} ,{f4[t]} }, ... }
```

What `Plot` wants to see as input (check out the help file by hitting F1 on the word `PolarPlot` to see the exact wording) is a list of functions like

```
{f1[t], f2[t], f3[t], ... }
```

`Flatten` removes all the curly brackets from the original list to give the desired form.

Comment: Thank you.  I think I may be best off to clarify the question as being "How does PolarPlot handle nested lists of functions?"  I would like to understand what `PolarPlot` is doing when it encounters something like `{{f1[t]},{f2[t]}}` as its first argument.